How to use IEndpointRouteBuilder in Razor class library
I have a Blazor component that I want to be standalone, so I can use it in SSR and Wasm
SignalR is also used in this component
I want to let the user can use the component with minimal settings
I plan to implement this method extension, but the package I need to use for it depends on the component to SSR. Is there a solution?
This method extension depends on the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" package, but this package makes the component dependent on SSR.
public static IEndpointRouteBuilder MapActivePageConnectionsAutoModeHub(this IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)

{ 
endpoints.MapHub<UsersOnlineHub>("/UsersOnlineHub");

return endpoints;

}


could you please share which version you are using with your RCL project? You can add  the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App package in RCL, after adding this package, you can use IEndpointRouteBuilder in RCL. as far as i know IEndpointRouteBuilder depends on Micrsoft.AspNetCore.Routing. Is it possible for you to share the reproducible sample with us so that i will be easy for us to guide you.
